# Cant read one property from xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a weird problem. I have this datatype that stores information read from a xml-file.
The class (the important parts) looks like this:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class myClass
    {
        #region XML Properties
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name;

        [XmlAttribute("prop1")]
        public string prop1;

        [XmlAttribute("prop2")]
        public string prop2;

        [XmlAttribute("prop3")]
        public char prop3;

        ...etc...
        public myClassList readXml(string xml_file)
        {
            myClassList myList = new myClassList();

            XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myClassList));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(xml_file, FileMode.Open);
            myList = (myClassList)mySerializer.Deserialize(fs);
            fs.Close();
            return myList;
        }
    }
```

The myClassList-class looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("myClassList")]
    public class myClassList : CollectionBase
    {
        public virtual void Add(myClass c)
        {
            this.List.Add(c);
        }

        public virtual myClass this[int Index]
        {
            get
            {
                return (myClass)this.List[Index];
            }
        }
    }
```

short part of the xml-file:

```
<myClassList>
    <myClass Name="test" prop1="test2" prop3="blabla" ...[etc] />
</myClassList>
```

And then I try to use it like this:

```
myClassList test = myClass.readXml("C:\\test\\file.xml");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("name"+test[0].Name);
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("name"+test[0].prop1);
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("name"+test[0].prop2);
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("name"+test[0].prop3);
```

Everything works fine with prop1, prop2, prop3 etc. but not for Name.
Why not? To me they all look the same. what am I missing?
(I haven't designed this, so I'm not 100% sure of how it all works)

**EDIT:**
As suggested by SoMoS, I tried using xsd.exe (first time I used, so I might have done wrong.) I used the command `xsd myFile.xml /o:E:\temp` and got a new file. In the new file it looks like this:

```
...
<xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
<xs:attribute name="prop1" type="xs:string" />
<xs:attribute name="prop2" type="xs:string" />
<xs:attribute name="prop3" type="xs:string" />
...
```

Does this help anyone?

Comment: Could it be that Name is a reserved keyword in this situation as you are dealing with XML files?

Comment: no, name is just what I called it here. In my actual code it's named differently (definetly not reserved name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of debugging and testing I realized that the file path became overwritten from another method. Once I fixed that, everything worked. So the issue were never the xml-reading, but rather another method that changed the path <.<

Answer (score 1):

I would use the xsd.exe tool to generate the XML class reader so you can spot the differences.

Check here: [XSD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I really don't know what's going on but the fact that the tool didn't generate the attribute is pointing that something happens. I recommend using the following command: xsd myFile.xml /o:E:\temp /c and looking at the generated classes.

Comment: It did generate the name attribute :P but I'll try ur suggested command

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson: ooooops, sorry. Seems that I'm a bit sleepy this morning :P Ok, the main goal of using xsd.exe was to look how it creates the classes so you create them in the same way, so using /C is essential.

Comment: I solved it... I'm probably also sleepy, because the sollution was really stupid ^^ check my answer if you are interested :P thx for the help